# Mkdirs failed to create file in Kubernetes - Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, kubernetes-pod

I am using the Flink Operator in Kubernetes to deploy Apache Flink cluster in Appication mode and having permission issues. I have Filestore instance mounted as a ReadWriteMany Volume. I can access the mounted volume "/flink-data" when I "kubectl exec" to the taskmanager pod. I can also create directories inside.
However, whenever the checkpointing gets triggered, I still get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/flink-data/checkpoints/f6dc4b42c99ac5d25f4be4771a9c6889/chk-1
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.create(LocalFileSystem.java:262) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.6.jar:1.13.6]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.create(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:130) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.6.jar:1.13.6]
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.EntropyInjector.createEntropyAware(EntropyInjector.java:61) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.6.jar:1.13.6]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory$FsCheckpointStateOutputStream.createStream(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:401) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.6.jar:1.13.6]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory$FsCheckpointStateOutputStream.flushToFile(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:258) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.6.jar:1.13.6]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory$FsCheckpointStateOutputStream.write(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:234) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.6.jar:1.13.6]
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out and resolve the permission issue. After checking the Apache Flink docker image that led me to this file -  https://github.com/apache/flink-docker/blob/master/1.13/scala_2.12-java8-debian/docker-entrypoint.sh ... I was running the image as root instead of "9999" which was flink's uid and gid.
I created an initContainer to change ownership of the mounted pvc from root to flink.